# TrueCrypt and NTFS partition problem

Tags: mount, encryption, ntfs

I can't mount a TrueCrypt partition (yesterday everything was ok). When I just map and decrypt it without mounting - then it is ok. However, I can't fix it (the partition type is NTFS) or mount using -t ntfs or -t ntfs-3g. However, fixntfs reports no error:

```
zmicier@zmicier-Latitude-7480:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/mapper/truecrypt1 
[sudo] password for zmicier: 
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/mapper/truecrypt1 was processed successfully.
zmicier@zmicier-Latitude-7480:~$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/mapper/truecrypt1 encrypted_drive/
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to calculate free MFT records: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
zmicier@zmicier-Latitude-7480:~$
```

There is another non-encrypted NTFS partition on this drive and it works finely.

When I try to mount encrypted partition on Windows using TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt, then it is being mount for about 10 minutes and when it is fortunately mounted every operation on that drive hangs indefinitely. It there a way to recover this partition?

Comment: What is your underling hardware, SDD or spinning disk?  How long has the Truecrypt partition been in use?  Using a small Truecrypt file, I burned through an SDD's write capability in only 9 months.

Comment: It is a portable 4tb WD HDD. I used it rarely - only when attach to a laptop (probably 10 hours of spinning in the whole 2 years). I had two more truecrypt HDDs which I used more intense and for longer period of time and they are fine. In case of this disk it is strange that normal (non-encrypted partition) is ok and also there is no problem to decrypt and map ntfs partition (the problem is mounting only). Seems like filesystem corruption but it is strange that ntfsfix and mount messages are completely different.

Comment: Try using Windows repair tools to check/fix the ntfs filesystem.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu version is 20.04 but yesterday the filesystem was ok. I tried to use chkdsk /f on that drive on Windows but I'm not sure if there is any progress - maybe it just hangs.

Comment: Truecrypt has not been maintained for 6 years now.

Comment: TrueCrypt works finely now and also you may use VeraCrypt to work with TrueCrypt volumes. The problem is not with the encryption but with the partition itself.

Comment: In 21 with a half hours chkdsk /f reported "unexpected error" and stopped...